# Programmatically choose language for translation

Tags: translation

I have a multilanguage website (to do it I use both Polylang and Loco Translate).

My problem is that I want to send an email to our users, but I don't know in which language to send it until I retrive the record from the DB (so I can't simply set a different WP_LANGUAGE)

This is pseudocode for what I would like to do:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT userName,language FROM wp_order WHERE id =%s",$id_order));

$result = $wpdb->last_result;

if($result){

   //SET LANGUAGE FOR TRANSLATION $result->language

   $emailBody= "Hi".$result->name." "._("text to translate","pluginname");

   /* ... generate email ... */

   wp_mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the l10n.php I found a way to switch the textdomain using the unload_textdomain function.

So I created a simple switch

```
function switch_textdomain( $domain, $newLocale){
   /*
    This will only change the textdomain, not the locale.
    It will only affect what kind of language will be used for the _e(), _(), __() commands for the $domain
   */

   unload_textdomain( $domain );

   /*mofile Folder
     this may have to be changed depending on what you want to switch*/
   $path = get_template_directory();
   $mofile = "{$path}/{$newLocale}.mo";

   return load_textdomain( $domain, $mofile );

}
```

This will not actually change the locale, but will only change the textdomain for the specified domain (your theme, or plugin).

Since in my case I only needed the translation this is good enough for me.